# Best way to design data table for unknown number of columns?

Tags: database, reporting

I am trying to build a data table structure that will best support the following criteria:

1) I do not know how many columns the table has to have.

- I might need 6 columns in some cases, or 10 in others. I do not expect this table ever need 20 or more columns, but I also can't guarantee that won't ever be needed.

2) I need to take into account storage space and reporting speed.

- This table will need to stored millions of records, and reports will be run against this table. I know pivoting out highly normalized tables is difficult from a reporting perspective, so I want to de-normalize for reporting. But, I also don't know if simply defaulting to some large number of columns in order to avoid some normalization is a good idea because I'll probably end up with lots of NULLS in many of the columns on the end of the table, and those will (I think) all take up some amount of storage space.

3) If I have to choose between storage space and report performance, I will side with performance.

I am not a Business Intelligence expert, and I am not a T-SQL guru (I'll be using SQL Server), and so I am SURE there are fine points here I have simply overlooked. Thus, I am turning once again to the brilliant SO community for advice, and to have some sense knocked into my thick skull.

How would you design the table under these circumstances? What details am I missing and still need to consider?

Comment: Is there a reason, besides your brief mention of difficult pivoting, that you are shying away from a `product_property` and `product_property_value` set of tables?

Comment: Kevin --Doesn't product_property and product_property_value have it's own issues? Everything (dates, numbers) should be stored as strings, constraints are difficult to implement, and of course, pivoting for even the very basic "select" queries.

Comment: My understanding of these things is limited, but I was shying away from that for the reasons cited by Rajesh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most generic-table designs where the column values are decided based on user settings/so will lead to poor performance since all queries will be dynamic.

The reasonable thing to do would be to come up with an estimate on the number of columns and let the unused ones be null initially.

Can you give an example as to what your tale is for? One of the examples that raises this question is when you have a product table and some products have only 5 attributes and some have 50. As I said above, you are better off creating the table with 50 columns (if you want to have a single product table) and having the other columns as null where required.

Reporting tools and most RDBMSs handle nulls well during aggregation and grouping.

Comment: Rajesh, you've got a perfect understand of my problem. I will, in fact, be building these tables for products with some unknown number of attributes. Some products will have 6 attributes, while others could have 10. Though, I don't see the number exceeding 10 by much. Thus, I was thinking about defaulting to 20, but wasn't sure if that was the right way to go or if I was oversimplifying the problem. Most importantly, I want to know what I am failing to consider :)

Answer (score 8):

The columns of the table represent the specifications of the entity to be stored. To say that you do not know how many columns will be stored means you do not know the specification of the stuff to be stored. Said another way, you want to build a system without know what it will store. Relational databases are fundamentally not designed to handle this *and perform well and be maintainable*. To perform well and be maintainable, relational databases rely on spending the time to determine the nature of the entity to be stored and its attributes and then building the appropriate schema.

Thus, the best performing and most maintainable solution using a relational database is to build out the schema as it is required which means gathering the specs on what is to be stored as it is needed.

That said, there are alternatives to relational databases such as so called "nosql" databases which might fit the need of an uber-elastic design better than a relational database. Examples of these include MongoDB and CouchDB.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. I have to wonder though, what do you do when you -really- don't know how many columns will be needed, and there is no way to know? I mean, I can decide that I will probably never need more that X number of columns, but I am building these tables to store an unknown number of products, which each come with an unknown number of their own attributes to store ...

Comment: @campbelt - Tables in relational databases were not designed to store a sets of arbitrary things. E.g., the structure that you would want for storing automobiles is different than the structure you would want for storing laptops, clothing, nuclear submarines or movie clips. Is it *possible* to create a structure in a RDBMS to store "things" with no schema? Sure, but it will not peform well nor be maintainable and if reporting and performance (and scale) are important then a RDBMS isn't the right tool. It is akin to using Excel to write a book.

Comment: @campbelt - Given the above, if instead the spec on this additional data is that it is to be an arbitrary wad of data that will never be queried for, analyzed, used in mathematical calculations, filtered on, sorted on or any way used other than to spit the entire contents for each product out to report, then there are solutions for that. However, those solutions all require discipline to not treat this wad of data like a standard column but instead like a blob of notes.